# PHP Extraer los últimos registros de una tabla

Tags: php

Estoy intentando extraer los últimos cinco registros de una tabla pero me imprime cinco veces el último registro.

```
<?php 
// realizamos la conexión a la base de datos 
$user = 'root'; $pass = ''; 
$host = 'localhost'; 
$db = 'rasptemp'; 
$config = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'UTF8'");
try
{
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;", $user, $pass, $config);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e -> getMessage();
}

// realizamos la consulta para obtener el mayor id insertado
$sql = "SELECT id, temperatura, humedad FROM temp ORDER BY fecha DESC LIMIT 5";
$query = $conn->prepare($sql);
$query->execute();
$row = $query->fetch();

// imprimimos los 5 valores obtenidos
do {
    echo $row['temperatura'].' - '.$row['humedad']. ' - ' . $row['id'] . '<br>';
} while ($rows = $query->fetch());
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dentro del bucle `while` estás haciendo referencia a `$row` PERO en la condición inicializas la variable `$rows`… Cámbiala a `$row`.

Comment: Si es verdad, fallo grande jajaja, gracias por l'ayuda!

Comment: Si la respuesta es la correcta… Márcala como tal, por favor :)